# Domains and subdomains virtualhosts with different SSL certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I have a domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and I need this domain to be reachable both via https and http.
I have a certificate (GeoTrust) that protects [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com.

I need to protect app.example.com, as well.
app.example.com is somthing that needs to be reachable ONLY via https, but it doesn't need a proper certificate: a self signed one is enough.

I tried many different configurations (even using the same certificate for both the main domain and the subdomain), but nothing worked!
The following configuration is the latter I tried but the result is that if I connect to app.example.com, it tells me the connection is untrusted and then, once accepted, it redirects me to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)!

Any help? thank you.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/websiteexample/public/www"
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        <Directory "/var/websiteexample/public/www">
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/websiteexample/public/www"
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/www.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/www.example.com.key
        <Directory "/var/websiteexample/public/www">
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/another/app"
        ServerName app.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/app.example.com.pem
        <Directory "/path/to/another/app">
            allow from all
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- added `SSLEngine on`  to serverconfig
- added `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on`  to serverconfig - SNI for multiple certificates, exclude non SNI capable clients
- added `SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/app.example.com.key` - you need a private key for both vhosts

Here is the new configuration:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:-MEDIUM

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/websiteexample/public/www"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    <Directory "/var/websiteexample/public/www">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/websiteexample/public/www"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    #You might also need: SSLCertificateChainFile 
    SSLCertificateFile /root/www.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/www.example.com.key
    <Directory "/var/websiteexample/public/www">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/another/app"
    ServerName app.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /root/app.example.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/app.example.com.key
    <Directory "/path/to/another/app">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank for your help, but unfortunately Apache fails to reboot with an error on this directive: SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on.
I tried to Google for an explanation but I couldn't find out which directive I have to enable in order to make it work...

Comment: what apache version do you use? did you enable modssl? could you post the errror message?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do name-based vhosting with SSL because the name comes from the "Host:" header, which is part of what's encrypted. You would need to choose the key before knowing which key to choose.

Generally, one uses an additional IP address for each unique keypair. You can find some great examples and explanation at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Comment: You might want to read about [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Comment: I believe this to be currently untrue in some setups. I have a VPS setup with a single IP address and name-based hosts (although using Nginx rather than Apache), and each one has its own SSL setup. Note that you can't use any advanced features (such as Extended Validation) with this setup, but assuming you're not too worried about verifying my identity it's trivial for me to encrypt communications to my website so that passwords and suchlike aren't sent in plain text.

Comment: People really need to stop replying with myths about SSL. SNI has been around for a bit now, it just happens to not work on a particularly shitty OS.

Comment: @gparent: SNI has been around for a bit now, but not working in IE in Windows XP is still a pretty big support gap.

Comment: Never said it wasn't.